# Would it be possible to change literals in the model below to reference values from an external file for localization or quick user changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given users who change their minds a thousand times.  How could I change the literals below to come from a config file or something similar?

```
namespace mvc3test.Models
{

    public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also, doesn't this defeat part of the purpose of MVC? Which is to separate the logic from the presentation layer? Isn't the text to display on the screen very presentation specific?

Comment: do you want the validation error messages to be configurable or the types of validation attributes on a particular property?

Comment: @Eranga - I was more focused on the Display Attribute. really anywhere you see a literal in this example, so `Current Password`, `The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.`, and `New Password`,  Now imagine them all needing to be rewritten to be more customer friendly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes(eg [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx)) have `ResourceType` and `Name` properties. These can be used with a Resource file to externalize the literals and thereby localizing and/or changing literals. Have a look at this [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-2-using-modelmetadata.aspx).

Comment: Your solution appears that it might work for one single *.resx file.. The problem comes in with VSS2010 not being able to figure out how to generate the code for a file with the naming convention *.*.resx It will only generate an empty *.cs file.

Comment: @Doug Resource files are also class files that inherit from ResourceManager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx class. So if you give a legal class name it should work

Comment: I'm suggesting there is a bug in the IDE, not that you are incorrect.  I do see there is a workaround. thanks for the link